# How do I automatically mount a plain-encrypted USB flash drive to my OpenWRT router?

Tags: usb-drive, openwrt, disk-encryption

I just finished encrypting my external hard drive using a key file, and mounting it onto [my router](http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/barrier.breaker). Problem is, every restart i have to manually recreate the mapping and mount it again.

OpenWRT's documentation appears to have a lot to say about [auto-mounting normal hard drives](http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/uci/fstab), but I don't see much on auto-mounting plain-encrypted hard drives. Google suggests using `/etc/crypttab`, which doesn't seem to exist on my OpenWRT system.

How do I automatically mount my plain-encrypted external?

Comment: How did you encrypt your drive? The solution is likely to depend on the method you used. [Have a look here for a comparison table](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Disk_encryption#Comparison_table) :)

Comment: @JohnWHSmith My external was encrypted using plain `dm-crypt` (no LUKS--couldn't get it to work) and the `cryptsetup` program.

Answer (score 1):

I deleted the earlier answer because it was inadequate.

**Warning: I tried this solution on a virtualbox image of openwrt (ATTITUDE ADJUSTMENT (12.9, r36088)), may be it slightly differs on the router.**

I assume that the key file is /root/keyfile and that used cipher is aes-xts-plain. You have to change the values according to your setup.

If You want I can tell you how enable luks extensions on openwrt.

Assuming that your system already supports cryptsetup and all the various ciphers, you have to act at the level of hotplug, because the implementation of cryptosetup of openwrt not seem to support the /etc/crypttab (probably should be recompiled the boot image)

install support for hotplug

```
root@OpenWrt:~# opkg install block-mount
```

open /etc/hotplug.d/usb/10-usb, in my system the file looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Copyright (C) 2009 OpenWrt.org


case "$ACTION" in
        add)
                # update LEDs
                ;;                     
        remove)            
                # update LEDs
                ;;           
esac
```

I've edited the file:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Copyright (C) 2009 OpenWrt.org


case "$ACTION" in
        add)
                # update LEDs
                exec logger "PRD:" ${PRODUCT};
                ;;                     
        remove)            
                # update LEDs
                ;;           
esac
```

from a terminal connected to the router, before you insert the disc, tail the logs:

```
root@OpenWrt:~# logread -f|grep PRD
```

Connect the USB disk, you should see a line like:

```
Oct 29 10:43:48 OpenWrt user.notice root: PRD: 13fe/3600/100
```

**Take note the string after PRD: it is used to identify your disk to decrypt**

Now the hotplug mechanism first call the scripts located in /etc/hotplug.d/usb then the script 40-mount in /etc/hotplug.d/block. 
The data of the device and the mount point are passed through environment variables, but I could not understand how it is possible to communicate to the 40-mount script that we want to mount the encrypted partition using env variables. 
So I opted for a less elegant but still functional.
I modified the file /etc/hotplug.d/usb/10-usb

```
#!/bin/sh

# Copyright (C) 2009 OpenWrt.org
PRODID="13fe/3600/100"
case "$ACTION" in
    add)
        # update LEDs
        if [ "${PRODUCT}" = "${PRODID}" ];
        then
            touch /tmp/crypt
        fi
        ;;
    remove)
        # update LEDs
                if [ "${PRODUCT}" = "${PRODID}" ];      
                then            
                        rm /tmp/crypt
            fi           

        ;;
esac
```

When the encrypted disc is inserted the file /tmp/cryp is created, this file il deleted when the disc is removed. 
So I edited the file /etc/hotplug.d/block/40-mount:

```
case "$ACTION" in
        add)

### AUTO DECRYPT
            if [ -e /tmp/crypt ];
               then
                  /usr/sbin/cryptsetup -c aes-xts-plain create -d /root/keyfile cryptousb /dev/$device;
                  device="mapper/cryptousb"
                  mountpoint="/mnt/cryptousb"
                  sleep 10
            fi
#### END AUTO DECRYPT
```

And:

```
remove)                          
### AUTO DECRYPT               
          if [ -e /tmp/crypt ];
             then           
                /usr/sbin/cryptsetup remove cryptousb;
                device="mapper/cryptousb"
                mountpoint="/mnt/cryptousb"
                sleep 10                 
        rm /tmp/crypt
          fi

#### END AUTO DECRYPT
```

When the disc is inserted and it's PRODID is recognized, before mounting the encrypted volume is open and mapped, then the name of the device and the mount point are changed.
The sleep is necessary to wait cryptosetup process is completed.
When you umount the volume, the map in /dev/mapper is removed.

Hope this works for you

Comment: Now this looks promising (if only my laptop's boot loader didn't crap out on me, I could test it now)! Quick question: Is the `rm /tmp/crypt` line in `40-mount` necessary? I thought it was being handled by `10-USB`...

Comment: @NoobSaibot yes you can omit the rm command in 40-mount